# JavaScript not using variables from other JS files

Tags: javascript, html, variables, web, include

I'm pretty new to JS and I'm trying to pull variables from other files. I am having an issue with this though, I am importing all the JS files in what I have seen (looked around a lot before asking this) to be correct order. I also have tried using object creation like "Filename moduleName = new Filename();" then calling things set in that instance like "moduleName.variableName" this does not work either. I have made a Repl.it for this issue and here it is: https://repl.it/EGfc/5

If anyone has any suggestions, questions, comments or concerns please ask or say them!
Thanks,
Aaron

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually you have not declared  the `testForOne` variable
in `ContainsOne.js` **before** the function. That's why it is undefined in `Compile.js`. I've made some changes in all your files to make clear how it works:

https://repl.it/EGfc/45

Comment: Thanks very much! This worked and makes sense! Have a good day!